# React navigation: React Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: Check the render method of `NavigationContainer`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just migrating react-navigation library into 3.0 as given in the example https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html and I finally ended with the following error. Not sure what does this error mean?

**Error**

[image]

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import HomeScreen from './screens/Home';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer/>;
  }
}
```

**HomeScreen:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**
If I render the Homescreen directly in App.js, I am just getting the home screen fine.

I mean call

```
export default HomeScreen;
```

instead of this

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <AppContainer/>;
      }
    }
```

Comment: i believe your error is in the HomeScreen, can you post the code for it?

Comment: @kivul Home screen just contains 'text'. See my edited post

Comment: I just ran the exact code you posted, and it's working, are your imports correct?

Comment: there is no issue with the code. Just check with the imports or clear the cache and run again

Comment: I have cleared cache and reinstalled all node modules. Still getting same error.